# How prevent posting if user posted in less than 2 days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to prevent data from being submitted if `current_user` has posted in less than 2 days ?

```
<%= form_for @post do |x|%>
<% x.text_area :content %>
<%= x.submit %>
```

Comment: Look at the user's last post's created time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if the current user's last post was >= 2 days ago...

```
if current_user.posts.last.created_at >= 2.days.ago
```

Comment: You probably want similar logic in the `Post` validations as well.